# Navigation menu shared between different companies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu, navigation, sharing

The technology being used are C#,  Asp.net MVC 2.0, JQuery, and CSS, .NET 3.5 .

We have a web application and have a main navigation menu which is heavily CSS and JQuery dependent with some Back-End data values.

The Navigation Menu is two layered – top layer and a sub-layer which takes the end user to the different areas of our application.

One of the requirement is for us to Navigate to our Partner site and when the customer navigates to their site the customer should get the same navigation menu as seen on our website.

The customer should not know that they are in the partner site website apart from the URL. The technology used by the Partner site may be a non-Microsoft stack.

What is the best way to share the Navigation Menu between the Web Sites?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can **create handler on your server side** which will return Back-End data values (navigation structure) **in acceptable for you format** (Json, XML, etc.), and also you can **separate styles and scripts for your navigation from all other** styles and scripts.

**Then your praters will be able to use your script and CSS files on their pages directly.**

Also they will be able to request data needed for navigation on their side.

Anyway you need to provide possibility for your partner to get all needed data/scripts/CSS.